# Have the Skull Woods Dungeon's wallmasters been made easier on Virtual Console?

Tags: nintendo-wii, version-differences, zelda-link-to-the-past

I am a long time fan and veteran player of *The Legend of Zelda: A Link to the Past* for the Super Nintendo, and I recently downloaded the Wii Virtual Console version of the game. Last night, I beat the Skull Woods dungeon on the Wii version, and noticed a significant difference in the difficulty level of this dungeon.

Specifically, the wallmasters (big read glove-monsters who drop from the ceiling) were noticeably slower, fewer, and further between. The constant threat of being caught by them and transported back to the starting point that was the distinctive hallmark of this dungeon in the SNES version, was suddenly and surprisingly barely even a concern. While I was playing, I was with a friend and fellow long-time player of this game who also agreed that the wallmasters seemed noticeably easier than those found in the paranoia-inducing SNES version he remembered. I searched the Internet for confirmation, hoping to find out whether it was publicly acknowledged that this change was made, and why, but have so far been unable to find anything of the sort.

Has anyone else played these games and noticed the same differences? Is there any information out there about whether this was an intentional choice made by Nintendo to attempt to make an annoying level less aggravating, or whether it was just a conversion error or other glitch? Any information would be much appreciated!

Comment: To my knowledge, Nintendo usually doesn't intentionally make changes to VC games unless its to support or disable certain features.  By support, I mean like how they made multiplayer work in Zelda Four Swords and by disable I mean like how they disabled the GB Printer in Zelda: Link's Awakening DX.

Comment: Having said that, it still could be an emulation error.

Comment: One method of checking could be to extract the ROM from the Wii Virtual Console version and see if the file matches the SNES original.